# Writing and Reading Learning in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever people learn a language, be it as a kid or as an adult, the speaking and listening processes are often separate from the writing and reading ones.

The first two are usually covered by the term **speech**. Speech development means improving speaking and listening skills.

I am looking for a similar word that would encompass writing and reading. We could say something like

> Before the age of 6, the children develop their speech, but it is only in primary school that they *learn to read and write*.

Is there a way to replace the italic part? And in particular the "read and write" part?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the word "literacy".

To be unable to read (and write) is to be *illiterate*. To have those abilities is to be *literate*

Note that this is similar to "numeracy", which relates to numbers.

Comment: In UK primary schools (well the one I know about at least!), the teachers & **children** use the terms literacy & numeracy to refer to two of their subjects. My son has a "literacy homework book".